# how I can properly get the aggregation of these fields

Tags: django

models

```
class Joint(models.Model):
    welder = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name='welders')
    inch_dia = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views

```
context['welder'] = Joint.objects.values('welder__first_name', 'welder__last_name')
            .order_by('welder__first_name') \
            .annotate(total_inch=Sum(F('inch_dia'))/Count(F('welder__first_name'))
            , output_field=IntegerField())
```

gives me the following error

```
QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>
```

i have checked with another similar table as follows and still the division is not happening

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class WorkDone(models.Model):
    worker = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, related_name='workers')
    work_title = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)
    units = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.work_title)
```

views for this table

```
  context['workers'] = Worker.objects.all() \
            .values('name', 'workers__work_title')\
            .order_by('name') \
            .annotate(total_work=
        Sum('workers__units')/Count('name')
        )
    print(context['workers'])
```

print output

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'dinesh', 'workers__work_title': 'first', 'total_work': 4}, {'name': 'ramesh', 'workers__work_title': 'first', 'total_work': 4}]>
```

instead of 4 it should be 2 as the total unit is 4 and no. of worker is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `output_field` is a parameter you pass to the `.annotate(..)` part. You can use an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper) to interpret the type of the value, or [**`Cast`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) to do conversions:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Joint.objects.values('welder__first_name', 'welder__last_name'
).order_by('welder__first_name').annotate(total_inch=Cast(
    Sum('inch_dia')/Count('welder__first_name'),
    output_field=IntegerField()
))
```

That being said, it might make more sense to annotate in the opposite direction:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Employee.objects.annotate(
    total_inch=Cast(
        Sum('welders__inch_data')/Count('welders'),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) specifies the name of the relation in *reverse*, so like `related_name='welders'` is incorrect, perhaps you want to rename this to:

```
class Joint(models.Model):
    welder = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name='joints')
    inch_dia = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then the query looks like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Employee.objects.annotate(
    total_inch=Cast(
        Sum('joints__inch_data')/Count('joints'),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, as you suggested, I have tried as shown in the last. The joints is always one, so what i want to do is division by no.of welders engaged on work. So I changed the count to first_name, but count always gives one, even though no.of welders are more than one.

Comment: @bmos: so the one with `Employee.objects`? Is it possible that you create *multiple* `Employee`s for the same (first) name?

Comment: Yes the Employees model. I queried with employee no also, which is unique, still the count is incorrect, is this the right way to count the many to many field?

Comment: @bmons: well the query it makes is ```SELECT `core_employee`.`id`, CAST((SUM(`core_joint`.`inch_dia`) / COUNT(`core_joint_welder`.`joint_id`)) AS signed integer) AS `total_inch` FROM `core_employee` LEFT OUTER JOIN `core_joint_welder` ON (`core_employee`.`id` = `core_joint_welder`.`employee_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `core_joint` ON (`core_joint_welder`.`joint_id` = `core_joint`.`id`) GROUP BY `core_employee`.`id```` (you can inspect that with `print(queryset.query)`, so it is grouping per `Employee`. Note that if you do not want to floor the result, you should *not* cast it to an `IntegerField`.

Comment: @bmons: I suspect that either something is not entirely correct with the data in the database; or you do not want to cast in to an `IntegerField` in the first place (in which case, you can drop the `Cast(..., outputField=IntegerField())`.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem: I have tested some other tables as shown in the updated qustion, still the divion is not proper as count of name is always one